# Working algorithm for PasswordDigest in WS-Security php

Tags: php, encoding, base64, sha1, amadeus

I have been creating hash password from the formula given by my airline supplier. I have search on this site and I got the solution from below link in C# but I want in PHP.
[Working algorithm for PasswordDigest in WS-Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19438000/working-algorithm-for-passworddigest-in-ws-security)

I have tried like this in php but  password digest which I am getting is wrong

```
function getTimestamp()
{
$microtime = floatval(substr((string)microtime(), 1, 8));
$rounded = round($microtime, 3);
return gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s") . substr((string)$rounded, 1, strlen($rounded))."Z";
}
$nounce = base64_encode(mt_rand(10000000, 99999999)); 
$timestamp = getTimestamp(); 
$password = "AMADEUS"; //clear password
$final_hashed_password = base64_encode(sha1($nounce.$timestamp.sha1($password)));
```

My values are generating like this

```
Nonce: ODczNzczNzE=
Timestamp: 2014-09-21T06:36:31.328Z
password: "TEST"
password digest I got: NjQxOThmZjViNmIwOGM0NGNiNDE1YTExNWQ3MDc2OGNlYjBjZDY2MA==
```

but password digest should generate like this

```
Right password digest: zGXsP85SuUngY7FjtnQizeO6yUk=
```

I know the algorithm for creating the Digest is:

```
Password_Digest = Base64 ( SHA-1 ( nonce + created + SHA-1 ( password ) ) )
```

Please help me to generate right hash password in php and also please see the above link which has the solution in c#

Comment: Hi, if you are looking at implementing the Amadeus Web Services SOAP interface in PHP, perhaps you'll be interested in a PHP composer package which does this (and more) for you: https://github.com/amabnl/amadeus-ws-client

Answer (score 3):

Got the solution!...we have to decode the nonce and then apply the formula on it and in xml we have to send the encoded nonce

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned - the issue was in Nonce.

If I may suggest, it may be better to use for nonce a stream of bytes (`random_bytes`), instead of `mt_rand(10000000, 99999999)` without encoding it. And then, only encode it when you'll be including it in the Nonce SOAP/XML node.