# What are the things required to connect the amadeus api?

Tags: web-services, web, amadeus

I have an API,Office ID,Username,password for the Amadeus API .

Can some one plz guide me how to connect the Amadeus API step by step for making the reservation(PNR Creation).

I have checked their home page and i could not get the detailed things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in luck - such a guide already exists :)

Documentation on how to get connected can be found on [webservices.amadeus.com](https://webservices.amadeus.com) by going to Technical doc -> WBS -> Handbook -> Framework documentation

Once you're connected, there's a specific guide to do flight search and make bookings based on the results of a flight search called *Amadeus WBS Implementation Guide - Internet Booking Engine with Master Pricer*. You can find this under Functional doc -> WBS -> PNR -> PNR_AddMultiElements

Hope that helps!

Comment: Can i get the exact link plz upto the framework documentation ? so that it will be helpful for me. @Tadhg

Comment: Sure, you need to be logged in to webservices.amadeus.com first for the link to work: 
https://webservices.amadeus.com/extranet/kdbViewDocument.do?externalId=wikidoc_wbs_frameworks&docStatus=Published&mpId=fla__1__technical

Comment: Also, this question may help you when dealing with the password digest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25956587/working-algorithm-for-passworddigest-in-ws-security-php

Answer (score 1):

[this](https://github.com/amabnl/amadeus-ws-client) will help you only whatever is available on internet is useless related to this